# why the model is not received by the controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Razor code:

```
 @model Clarifi.API.DataContract.ManualScanItem
    @using (Html.BeginForm(new { @class = "pull-left" }))
    { 
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ItemType)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ItemIdentifier)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hotel.Address.AddressLine1)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hotel.Address.AddressLine2)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hotel.Address.CityCode)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hotel.Address.CityName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hotel.Address.CompleteAddress)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hotel.Address.CountryCode)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hotel.Address.StateCode)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hotel.Address.StateName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hotel.Address.ZipCode)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hotel.ClarifiId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hotel.GeoCode.Latitude)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hotel.GeoCode.Longitude)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hotel.GeoCode.GeoCodeSource)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hotel.HasIssue)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hotel.Name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hotel.PhoneNumber)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hotel.Rating)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hotel.SupplierFamily)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hotel.SupplierId)

        <input type="submit" value="Verify" class="button-orange btn-action mtm btn-validate">
    }
```

Action in controller:

```
public ActionResult MapGeoCode(ManualScanItem hotelModel)
        {
            ItemRs<ManualScanItem> response = manualScanProvider.GetNextScanItem(ManualScanItemType.GeoCodeScan);

            if (!response.IsSuccess)
            {
                //this.SetErrorView(response);
                return View("ErrorView");
            }

            return View(response.Item);
        }
```

I've even checked the http request. There also the input data is going. But In my controller action, the 'hotelModel' is null. What to do? And why it is so?

Comment: Do you have the HttpGet and HttpPost anotation above the method? Is the name of the get method the same as MapGeoCode?

Comment: I tried both with putting [HttpPost] and without putting it... but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

You pass the model to the view somewhere? Something like:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult MapGeoCode()
    {
        return View(new ManualScanItem());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MapGeoCode(ManualScanItem hotelModel)
    {
        ItemRs<ManualScanItem> response = manualScanProvider.GetNextScanItem(ManualScanItemType.GeoCodeScan);

        if (!response.IsSuccess)
        {
            //this.SetErrorView(response);
            return View("ErrorView");
        }

        return View(response.Item);
    }
```

Comment: Yaa.. It was not working don't know what I was missing. Anyway, I've made it with the help of FormCollection and then translating that into my local model

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MapGeoCode()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MapGeoCode(ManualScanItem hotelModel)
{
    ItemRs<ManualScanItem> response = manualScanProvider.GetNextScanItem(ManualScanItemType.GeoCodeScan);

    if (!response.IsSuccess)
    {
        return View("ErrorView");
        //or return get action
        return View(response.Item);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And try this in view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MapGeoCode", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "pull-left" }))
{
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this overload instead..

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("actionname", "controllername", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "your class name" })) { 

}
```